Wordpress Multi-site subdirectory not working on server only on localhost
I'm looking into using Wordpress Multi-site to have a three separate wordpress sites on one installation of Wordpress.
I have the Mulit-site set up and I can add sites but I have one admin log in to the multi site Dashboard showing all the sites.
Is it possible to have separate logins that login into the separate sites.
So if I have a cars website it would have it's own dashboard that the cars-admin could log into but wouldn't be able to see the multi-site dashboard.
i try to use my main super admin and still same , also crate user and add the option to be on all the netword and its sill the same i get lots of 404 page if i try to use sub siteenter image description here
this is when i try to go to this url {i have another domain not example.com ofcurs) https://example.com/ch/wp-admin/admin.php?page=astra
and i take one of the url for exmaple this one https://example.com/ch/wp-content/themes/astra/admin/assets/theme-builder/build/index.rtl.css?ver=4.7.3 isn't working 404 if i just remove the subdomain https://example.com/ch/ like this /wp-content/themes/astra/admin/assets/theme-builder/build/index.rtl.css?ver=4.7.3
